# How to access 'm' in a: {m: 67; n:87} , where a is javascript Object

Tags: javascript

During question solving, I came across a code problem:

```js
var a = {};
a: {m: "something"; n: "another thing";}
```

Now if I want to access `m` or `n` here, how am I suppose to?
And where can this kind of code be used in practice?

Answer (score 5):

The code posted is not useful; it does not actually do anything. It's probably designed as a trick question.

```
var a = {};
a: {m: "something"; n: "another thing";}
```

In that code, `a:` is a **label**, and the `{ }` block following it is a block of statements. That block *also* contains labeled statements, `m` and `n`. Thus the code is equivalent to

```
var a = {};
{
   "something";
   "another thing";
}
```

You can prove this to yourself by adding more statements to the block

```
var a = {};
a: {m: "something"; n: "another thing"; console.log("in the block!"); }
```

Any statement in JavaScript can have a label, but labels are only useful in conjunction with the `break` and `continue` statements. Labels should therefore only be used with looping statements like `for` and `while`.

Comment: i don't think so that's a valid statement that i am looking for. We got confused simply because we have never used. This i have never used before, may be it can be  beneficial in some way, only that i want to know, not that its confusing or something cz i get that obviously :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has the concept of `label` statements. It allows us to name loops and blocks in JavaScript. We can then use these labels to refer back to the code later while using `break` or `continue`. **Hence, we can only use labels with break and continue.**

```
foo: {
  console.log('face');
  break foo;
  console.log('this will not be executed');
}
console.log('swap');

// this will log:

// "face"
// "swap
```

***If it is not about label statement*** because your posted code is not useful for this concept, then you can remove extra `;` add comma `,` and finally get value of `m`

```js
var a = {};
a = {
  m: "something",
  n: "another thing"
};
console.log(a.m);
```

Comment: That exactly what i thought, but amazingly the above javascript code snippet is valid.

Comment: This code does something completely different than the code in the question.

Comment: i have used this particular code snippet by you like a million times.

Comment: exactly @Pointy .

Comment: @PriyankaGupta You can also try this: `console.log(a['m']);`

Comment: that's undefined sir @SaurabhAgrawal

Comment: ohh my bad. I just forgot about label concept!!